# Can this $dx$ be taken out?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this expression:

$$\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

Can the two $dx$ be "simplified"? Namely, to get

$$\frac{df(x)}{f(x)}=dg(x)$$

Is this right? If it is, **what is the reasoning to justify it?** I just don't feel right about it.

Whether this is valid or not, I have another question: **how can I get rid of the differentials in the equation**? I thought of integrating but I don't know if it would be correct, because I don't know between which limits do the integration.

Comment: Integrating both sides, you get $\ln(f(x))=g(x)+C$

Comment: @KennyLau So I just integrate without limits of integration?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You can also include limits of integration, then you get $\ln(f(x_1))-\ln(f(x_0))=g(x_1)-g(x_0)$. When $x_0$ is fixed and $x_1$ is variable this is basically the same as the indefinite case.

Comment: No the $dx$'s do not "simplify" or cancel.  You can integrate both sides by using the fact that an integral can be evaluated using an antiderivative (of which $f$ is certainly an antiderivative of $\frac{df}{dx}$).

Comment: As for the limits, it might be helpful to rewrite as $\frac{1}{f(t)}\frac{df(t)}{dt} = \frac{dg(t)}{dt}$ then integrate both sides with respect to $t$ from some value (whatever is convenient--you will find it must be $> 0$) to $x$.  The limits of integration are _very_ important as they will define a domain for which your final result is valid on (e.g. it's invalid for $x \leq 0$).  Otherwise, you need additional information to find a particular solution (a particular function)--specifically you need an initial condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac 1 f \frac {df} {dx}= \frac {dg}{dx} \iff \frac {f'}{f}=g' $$

Now, taking the indefinite integral on both sides: $\int \cdot\, dx$, we get $\ln f(x) = g(x)+c$.